# Laravel 5.3 Queues not working in shared hosting

Tags: php, laravel, cron, laravel-5.3, laravel-queue

In my Laravel 5.3.* application, I am having queues running in the background. This works completely fine in my local machine. But when this is made live on the server (shared hosting), it doesn't work at all.

Here's the scenario:

1. Administrator is submitting the admin generator form data.
2. Data is getting inserted in the database.
3. Shoot an email regarding the same.

So, in order to have this functionality going smoothly, I have created a cron job on my server's cPanel.

Here's the cron job:

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/<username>/laravel-app/artisan schedule:run >/dev/null 2>&1
```

And here's the `app/Console/Kernel.php` file content

```
/**
 * Define the application's command schedule.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
 * @return void
 */
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    // $schedule->command('inspire')
    //          ->hourly();

    $schedule->command('queue:work --daemon --tries=3')
             ->everyMinute()
             ->withoutOverlapping();
}
```

And I have also created the database for jobs by running

```
php artisan queue:table;
php artisan queue:failed-table;
php artisan migrate;
```

When the administrator is generated/inserted, an event is fired:

```
event(new AdministratorHasBeenGenerated($user, $request->password));
```

which will send a welcome email to the provided email id (in `app/Listeners/AdministratorHasBeenGenerated/SendWelcomeEmail.php`)

```
/**
 * Handle the event.
 *
 * @param  AdministratorHasBeenGenerated  $event
 * @return void
 */
public function handle(AdministratorHasBeenGenerated $event)
{
    Mail::to($event->administrator->email)
          ->queue(new GeneratedMail($event->administrator, $event->password));
}
```

And here's the mail configs in the .env file

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=correct_username
MAIL_PASSWORD=correct_password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

I don't receive any errors or things as such, but neither I receive any welcome email even though I provide correct email id.

---

**UPDATE 1: 21st December, 2017**

This is **just a work around** as I couldn't find the actual solution to this problem. What I did was I created another cron job for just running queues..

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/<username>/laravel-app/artisan queue:work --daemon --tries=3 >/dev/null 2>&1
```

This will fire the command `queue:work` every minute (or whatever you set it in the cron jobs tab in your cPanel)..

The above solution is not correct, I guess.. Corrections / amendments are most welcome.

---

Can anybody point out the mistake as to where and what I must have done? It has been more than 4 hours and I couldn't find any solution to this.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Any luck on this?

Comment: @joshuamabina I have updated the question.. Please check it..